# Sorting the most relation with Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Sorting the most relation with Doctrine?

**Relation**

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'users')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?University $university = null;
```

**My repository code ( Doesn't sort correctly )**

```
public function sortPopularChats(): array
{

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orderBy('u.university', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('u.university')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

**My user table**

```
|id|university_id|

|1|100610385|...
|2|106952005|...
|5|100610385|...
|11|108410557|...
|6|100610385|...
|7|106952005|...
|4|100610385|...
|9|106952005|...
|10|100610385|...
```

**Sorting should be like this**

1. 100610385
2. 106952005
3. 108410557
4. ...
5. ...

Comment: A little confused with the question. In your code, you set `OrderBy to University, Desc`. But then in the sample data below it, you show column name University_ID (not University). Lastly, you have the desired output ordered in ASC order.

Comment: university_id is an object. So it is not written as university_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `count` expression in order to be able to use it as the ordering field, but doing that it'll return a `ScalarResult`, with both the count and the object. To prevent that, you can use the [`HIDDEN` keyword](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) (scroll down or search for it) so only the `University` entities are returned:

```
public function sortPopularChats(): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->leftJoin('e.university', 'u')
        ->addSelect('u, count(u) AS HIDDEN uniCount')
        ->orderBy('uniCount', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy('u.id')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

Comment: Not working.  `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 26: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got 'AS'`

Comment: I messed up the order, should be `AS HIDDEN uniCount` (I think)

Comment: I think but it gives an error like this `[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT u, count(u)': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`

Comment: Thank you. I changed `select()`  like this and my problem was solved `addSelect()`

Comment: I edited answer to replace `select` by `addSelect`